# what is solution of this error:-Requests to this API must be over SSL

Tags: ssl, google-places-api

I am using Google Place API for getting the distance between two cities, but when I call the service via http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=dehli&destinations=pune&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=true&key=AppKey the  service gives this response:

```
{

    "destination_addresses": [ ],
    "error_message": "Requests to this API must be over SSL.",
    "origin_addresses": [ ],
    "rows": [ ],
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What's the solution for this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

HTTP over SSL protocol URLs are prefixed with `https://` and not `http://`.

Change [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=dehli&destinations=pune&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=true&key=AppKey(paste App Key)](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=dehli&destinations=pune&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=true&key=AppKey(paste%20App%20Key))
to [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=dehli&destinations=pune&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=true&key=AppKey(paste App Key)](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=dehli&destinations=pune&mode=bicycling&language=en-EN&sensor=true&key=AppKey(paste%20App%20Key))

Comment: I am getting following response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DirectionsResponse>
   <status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
   <error_message>This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address ***.***.***.***, with empty referer</error_message>
</DirectionsResponse>

Comment: Check the API . Whether it is generated for web / Android / ios. Coz api generated for iOS couldnt be used by web